# Using "this" keyword inside method of an object

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
var  main = function(){
    this.f = function(){
        console.log ( "nothing much");
    }
};

main.prototype.fun = function(){
    console.log ( "I am Fun");
    /*
      1st Here this will refer to Object of `main`. 
      But I want someway to bind f1 to fun not to main
    */
    this.f1 = function(){
        console.log ( "Help!");   
        return this;
    };

    this.f2 = function(){
        console.log ( "Print");
        return this;
    };

    /*
      2nd. Here again this will refer to Object of `main`. 
      But I want to return object of fun.
    */
    return this;
}
```

Now, I can achieve 1st point via following code, but that seems very long way ( 2nd problem is still there ):

```
main.prototype.fun.prototype.f1 = function(){
    console.log ( "Help FUN");
    return this;
};

main.prototype.fun.prototype.f2 = function(){
    console.log ( "Print FUN");
    return this;
};
```

How do you guys handle this scenario?

Comment: So you intend `main.prototype.fun` to be used as a constructor, like `var m = new main(); var f = new main.fun(); f.f1();`? I don't understand why you'd do that. Otherwise there is no `fun` object other than the function object.

Comment: Maybe to concatenate actions? `main.fun().f1().f2()`

Comment: @PatrickHofman: But there's no distinct `fun` object there other than the function itself. That can certainly be done, but it doesn't fit with what he's describing.

Comment: Just like @PatrickHofman said,  I actually want to do this `new main.fun().f1().f2()` , How do you handle such case?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal: You can do that with your existing code. So what's the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/7h32c/

Comment: @cookiemonster can we chat? If I follow above approach then `this.f1` will actually override the method if it is already there in `main`. But that's not my intention. SO used to have chat feature is it gone?

Comment: I think you'll be better off just editing your question to explain your situation more thoroughly.

Comment: Sorry, but I think your intent is entirely unclear. There are 100 different interpretations for what you might want, and none of them are probably right. From the looks of things, you're probably taking the wrong approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have 2 different class like functions here:

```
var Fun = function(){ };

Fun.prototype.f1 = function(){
  console.log ( "Help FUN");
  return this;
};
Fun.prototype.f2 = function(){
  console.log ( "Print FUN");
  return this;
};
```

Then define a property of `Fun` in your `Main`:

```
var Main = function(){ };
Main.prototype.fun = new Fun();
```

or like:

```
var Main = function(){
  this.fun = new Fun();
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var main = new Main();

main.fun.f1().f2();
```

or

```
main.fun.f2().f1();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can use arguments.callee;

```
var  main = function(){
    this.f = function(){
        console.log ( "nothing much");
    }
};
main.prototype.fun = function(){
    console.log ( "I am Fun");
    var scope=arguments.callee;
    scope.f1 = function(){
        console.log ( "Help FUN");
        return scope;
    };
    scope.f2 = function(){
        console.log ( "Print FUN");
        return scope;
    };
    return scope;
}

// test it
var test1=new main();
test1.f();
var test2=test1.fun();
test2.f1();
test2.f2();
```

Or,

```
var  main = function(){
    this.f = function(){
        console.log ( "nothing much");
    }
};
var fun=main.prototype.fun = function(){
    console.log ( "I am Fun");
    fun.f1 = function(){
        console.log ( "Help FUN");
        return fun;
    };
    fun.f2 = function(){
        console.log ( "Print FUN");
        return fun;
    };
    return fun;
}

// test it
var test1=new main();
test1.f();
var test2=test1.fun();
test2.f1();
test2.f2();
```

Comment: That just refers to the `fun` function. If he wanted to do that, he wouldn't need `arguments.callee` or a variable. He could just use `this.fun`.

Comment: using `arguments.callee` is not allowed in 'use strict' mode, so be careful about it. there is an alternative for it in ES5, using function names in the scope of the function, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) out for more information.